# How to enumerate pthread_t of all pthreads in current process?

Tags: pthreads

I need to control CPU affinity for all the pthreads in my process. Some pthreads are created by third-party libraries. Is there a way to enumerate the pthread_t of all existing pthreads in the process so that I can call pthread_setaffinity_np() on them?

EDIT: I'm mainly interested in recent Linux versions.

Comment: How portable does it have to be ?

Comment: your question seems to be a duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475750/posix-api-call-to-list-all-the-pthreads-running-in-a-process

Comment: Possible duplicate of [POSIX API call to list all the pthreads running in a process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475750/posix-api-call-to-list-all-the-pthreads-running-in-a-process)