# Find number of threads spawned by a process in Linux

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I want to write a c function , which when called by the process returns number of threads created by that process.
I want to get the value not by counting but from the kernel structure ?
Which structure has this information ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475750/posix-api-call-to-list-all-the-pthreads-running-in-a-process ?

Answer (score 2):

You can get a lot of information about your process by looking in `/proc/$$` where `$$` is your process ID.The number of threads is available atomically through `/proc/$$/status`.

My solution: You need write a function to analyse the file /proc/$$/status to get the number of threads.