# List all threads

Tags: c, unix, pthreads, posix, freebsd

How can I list all threads within the current process in FreeBSD? Or at least, get the number of threads running.

I found the Linux system call `pstat_getproc` which returns a struct containing `pst_nlwps`, the number of threads. I am looking for something similar to this on FreeBSD.

Or perhaps there is something like `/dev/fd` but for threads.

Anything I can use to get some kind of idea about how many other threads are running.

I want to be able to do this programmatically in C, not using an existing application.

Comment: Are you sure that `pstat_getproc` is a `Linux` syscall?

Comment: Perhaps this is what you're looking for? [libprocstat](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=libprocstat&sektion=3&apropos=0&manpath=FreeBSD%2010.0-RELEASE). Specifically, `procstat_getprocs`

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475750/posix-api-call-to-list-all-the-pthreads-running-in-a-process

Answer (score 2):

Use `procstat(1)`, *eg*

```
# procstat -t $(pgrep openvpn)
  PID    TID COMM             TDNAME           CPU  PRI STATE   WCHAN    
  537 100051 openvpn          -                  0  120 sleep   select
```

which depends on `libprocstat(3)`.

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified. I am not looking for a command line tool, I wish to do it programmatically in C.

Comment: @user2868331Look at /usr/src/usr.bin/procstat/procstat_threads.c.

Comment: ... and https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd-src/blob/main/usr.bin/procstat/procstat_basic.c as called from procstat.c as that has a simple field to access with the thread count rather than counting TIDs.