# Get all thread-ids of a running process with PThreads

Tags: c, linux, pthreads, bsd

I trying to debug a Pthread enabled program under Linux or FreeBSD. Thereby I require the id's (in terms of `pthread_t` thread identifiers) of all threads running in the program. For example as an array of `pthread_t`. But I am not able to modify the thread's function because on the one hand I do not have access to the source code of some libraries and on the other hand parts of the parallel code are implemented using OpenMP and there is no thread-function which I can modify.

Is there a portable way, to obtain the number of currently existing pthreads of a program and their `pthread_t` identifiers? The final thing I have to realize looks like

```
int n = get_number_of_threads(); 
pthread_t *threads = get_thread_list(); 
for ( i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    pthread_kill(threads[i], SIGUSR1); 
}
```

Comment: No. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475750/posix-api-call-to-list-all-the-pthreads-running-in-a-process

Comment: Possible duplicate of [POSIX API call to list all the pthreads running in a process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475750/posix-api-call-to-list-all-the-pthreads-running-in-a-process)