# Get threads information on macOS

Tags: c++, multithreading, macos, grand-central-dispatch

I need to trace some debugging information on the threads in my application, at least the name or maybe even only the count of them. Xcode does it wonderfully (showing the name of the dispatch queue) :

[image]

How can I replicate this using any technology? I looked a little bit to `NSTread` (`[NSThread callStackSymbols]` is beautiful, but only for the current thread) and `pthread`, `pthread_from_mach_thread_np` looks promising. Even an external call to `ps` is acceptable if nothing else.

Comment: If Xcode does it, why not use Xcode? Have you tried *”Instruments”*?

Comment: I needed in the application, as precised, as the app might do some useful log for later debugging, on another system.

Comment: Do you want (1) the count of threads, (2) the names of threads, or (3) the current function names executing in each thread?

Comment: @John Zwinck Preferable all of them ... If only I could enumerate them somehow (like `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot` on Windows, not asking much) ...

Comment: Start here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475750/posix-api-call-to-list-all-the-pthreads-running-in-a-process - but `/proc` doesn't exist on Mac OS.